# Access list of Custom Object in FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, snapshot, flutter-futurebuilder

I have a method, fetches some data from url and gets json array response like

```
Future<List<Images>> getData(String url) async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    return List<Images>.from(jsonDecode(response.body).map((x) => Images.fromJSON(x)));
}
response.body => [{"name":"img1","campaign_image_url":"http:\/\/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx\/development\/img1.jpg"},{"name":"img2","campaign_image_url":"http:\/\/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx\/development\/img2.jpg"}]
```

I have a Custom Object Called Images like

```
class Images {
  final String name;
  final String url;

  Images({required this.name, required this.url});

  Images.fromJSON(Map<String, String> json)
      : name = json['name']!,
        url = json['campaign_image_url']!;
}
```

I am using FutureBuilder to call a method `getData()` and loads data dynamically like

```
FutureBuilder<List<Images>>(
  future: getData(url),
  builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot<List<Images>> snapshot){
    if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error); //type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'
    if (snapshot.hasData) print(snapshot.data);
    return Container();
  }
)
```

Not able to get the data in `FutureBuilder` using `snapshot` and it is throwing snapshot error like `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'`

I tried these

- [Map List of objects from a Json response to a List in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64583151/map-list-of-objects-from-a-json-response-to-a-list-in-flutter)
- [Flutter future builder to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71218223/flutter-future-builder-to-list)

I am expecting something like `List<Images> lst = snapshot.data`. But Something is missing and throwing an error, I can't figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your `Images` class to the following:

```
import 'dart:convert';

Images imagesFromJson(String str) =>   Images.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String imagesToJson(Images data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Images {
    Images({
        required this.name,
        required this.url,
    });

    String name;
    String url;

    factory Images.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Images(
        name: json["name"],
        // the json["url"] should be exactly how you receive it from your backend
        url: json["url"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "url": url,
    };
}
```

Then use the `Images.fromJson()` as you normally would.

Comment: Thankyou so much!. This worked, but I didn't understand why are you suggesting me to keep parameter from json and the factory method variable to be same. They both are of different context and we are assigning the json value to that variable... Right?. Correct me If I am wrong. And also please explain why it is not working in my approach.

Comment: @ShashankGb here's a link that explains in details what is exactly Serialization in Flutter https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json

Answer (score 1):

In my project I faced the exact same issue. From what I read, its not directly possible to convert from an internal hashmap, I tried a lot of approaches on SO, but the following one solved my problem. I simply take the result, generate a new list where I iterate threw and access the needed data by index, and finally return the list type as the custom model, in your case Images (It's just an example, im not sure if yo access it by copy pasting my snippet, it should give you an idea what I did here):

```
final res = List.generate(snapshot.data.length, (i) {
        return Images (
          name: snapshot.data[i]['name'],
          url: snapshot.data[i]['campaign_image_url'],
        );
      });
```